# How to check if database is present and migrated in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to troubleshoot `500` error, on a Django REST framework + ReactJS app. I think the `migrate` is not executing correctly.

The `db-migrate.config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source $PYTHONPATH/activate pipenv run python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

`DB_SETTINGS`: eventually I want to change this to RDS

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

`eb deploy` is successful.

I still run into the `500` error, on `localmachine` the same endpoint works perfectly.

How can I check whether the database on Elastic Beanstalk has the necessary migrations? Any other causes I should be looking into?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: ("TIA" has been removed from a fair number of your posts, as has code formatting on software names).